# How can I determine if a rectangle intersects a right angle triangle?

Tags: c#, collision-detection, collision, intersection

I am trying to determine whether a rectangle intersects a triangle given the following triangle criteria:

1. the triangle will always be a right angle
2. the triangle will always derive from one of the corners of a rectangle
3. the triangle will always be the full width and height of the source rectangle

So one of my triangles can only be the top-left, top-right, bottom-left and bottom-right pieces of a rectangle.

Code would look similar to this:

```
Rectangle triangleSourceRect = new Rectangle(10, 10, 40, 40);

// top-left triangle from triangleSourceRect
Point[] topLeft = new Point[] {new Point(triangleSourceRect.Left, 
                                         triangleSourceRect.Top), 
                               new Point(triangleSourceRect.Left, 
                                         triangleSourceRect.Bottom),
                               new Point(triangleSourceRect.Right, 
                                         triangleSourceRect.Top)};

Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(28, 28, 20, 10);

if (bounds.Intersects(topLeft))
    return true;
```

This is a diagram of the above code:

[image: Triangle and Rectangle intersection diagram]

Comment: The [slope of a 45 degree line is 1](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_uOJHr1riEds/SfKatkwuSII/AAAAAAAAAGU/El3sxt3F_0s/s400/slope1.JPG) if you calculate re slipe of a line from the bottom left of the triangle and the top right of the rectangle and it is grater than 1 then they would intersect. Could that help?

Comment: Actually you can only check the four point of the green rectangle whether inside of triangle